# what the solution of Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, duplicates

I have tried to compile and I have no errors, but when I want to run the app I get this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: 
com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.class
```

my dependencies is :

```
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
    core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-
    annotations'
    })
    compile files('src/include/gson-2.8.2-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'io.searchbox:jest-droid:2.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed your question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40240414/how-to-solve-java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-com-google-gson-annotat)

As the accepted answer in that question states, you must multi-compiling GSON here

> compile files('src/include/gson-2.8.2-SNAPSHOT.jar')

and in another library... I'm going to assume it's this one:

> compile 'io.searchbox:jest-droid:2.0.1'

So I'd advise replicating the accepted answer for your project, like so:

```
compile('io.searchbox:jest-droid:2.0.1') {
exclude module: 'gson'
}
```